# Open fancybox iframe when click on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fancybox-2

Using fancybox2 and try to open YouTube video when click on div

```
<div class="vid" data-href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gGFXXWsCiVo?autoplay=1">This DIV should open fancybox</div>    

$(".vid").fancybox({
type: "iframe",
onStart: function (el, index) {
    var thisElement = $(el[index]);
    $.extend(this, {
        href: thisElement.data("href")
    });
  }
});
```

But its dosent work, please help.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulpodberezko/rtp7dntc/2/)

Comment: you may want to make things simpler http://stackoverflow.com/a/31226347/1055987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't know why you are complicating this fancybox thing like this,
Why do you need your 'thisElement' var? You should give us some more details to be sure we really understand what you need... I give you here some tips to open fancybox.. :

when you use fancybox, just start it like this :

```
//event function(){
$('.vid').click(function(){
    $.fancybox({
        //settings
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width'     : 640,
        'height'        : 480,
        //You don't need your thisElement var, see below : 
        'href'          : $(this).data('href')
    });
});
```

and put your settings into it,

here is a starting point for you, now just customize it to make it better for your needs :

http://jsfiddle.net/rtp7dntc/9/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you could improve your answer by actually showing the settings that you have in the jsfiddle (at least the `type` and `href` keys).

Comment: yes, you're right, I can :P (I will ;) ) -Here it is! :) -

Answer (score 1):

To make things much simpler you could use the special `data-fancybox` attributes on your `div` like

```
<div class="vid" data-fancybox-href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gGFXXWsCiVo?autoplay=1" data-fancybox-type="iframe">This DIV should open fancybox</div>
```

Then use a script as simple as this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.vid').fancybox();
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uu34rxzq/)**

**NOTE**:

The disadvantage of triggering fancybox programmatically as in the accepted answer is that it will only trigger a single fancybox but won't work for a gallery, while you can bind a fancybox gallery of several `div`s using the `data-fancybox-group` attribute.